# Aspx file generation

Tags: asp.net, file

I am working on an .aspx page.its to download a pdf that is generated in the aspx page.
.but when hosted in Amazon cloud i am getting the message.

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".
but on the subsequent invocation of the .aspx page  i am getting the pdf .
The pdf file is being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net uses separeted threads for each request. Probably you use some shared resources to generate pdf and don't clean up them. Therefore parellel requests may fail.
`Using` block (or calling `Dispose()` directly) may help.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\My Files\test.txt"))
{
    ..
}
```

Also make sure you don't open files with exclusive permissions like this:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: But the problem with me is that it happens only in the first time when i call the page in live